# How to merge multiple lines into single line but only for block of lines separated by blank line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, sh

I am trying to merge multiple lines into single one but with additional conditions.

My input file looks like:

```
Dm1*(  stuff1 + stuff2 -
stuff3 + stuff4)

+ D1*(D1stuff1 + D1sstuff2 + D1stuff3 + D1stuff4 +
  D1stuff5 - 
  D1stuff6 )

+ D2*(D2stuff)
```

So there are multiples lines which are also separated by blank lines. All the `*stuff*` contains long and complicated expressions which also can contain parenthesis.

#### I want to keep the blank lines as it is but merge the other multiple lines.

The expected output is

```
Dm1*(  stuff1 + stuff2 - stuff3 + stuff4)

+ D1*(D1stuff1 + D1sstuff2 + D1stuff3 + D1stuff4 + D1stuff5 - D1stuff6 )

+ D2*(D2stuff)
```

All the current attempts like

```
awk '{printf("%s",$0)}'
```

put everything in a single line. Should I loop over lines or is there any way to identify the blocks between blank lines and apply something into that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even a bit shorter than the version of John1024

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n"}{$1=$1}1'
```

or

```
awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '{$1=$1}1'
```

Using `RS=""` tells awk to use any paragraph as a record (i.e. a block of text separated by blank lines). But it also tells awk that a <newline> is always a field separator in combination with `FS`.  By just redefining the output record separator `ORS`, we can output everything as you want by telling awk to redefine its record `$0` by resetting the first record `$1=$1`. This has as effect that all field separators defined by `FS` (the default value here) and the newlines (due to `RS=""`) are replaced by `OFS` (default a <space;>). Finally we print the record with `1`

You can get rid of all the spaces when you additionally set `OFS=""`

> **`RS`** The first character of the string value of `RS` shall be the input record separator; a <newline> by default. If `RS` contains more than one character, the results are unspecified. If `RS` is `null`, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a <newline> plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX awk standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

Comment: there is a missing  `'` in the second before `{`?

Comment: Yup, that's the right/idiomatic way to do this with awk.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{if(NF!=0){printf $0}else{printf "\n\n"}}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ awk -v RS=  '{gsub(/ *\n */, " "); print $0 ORS}' file
Dm1*(  stuff1 + stuff2 - stuff3 + stuff4)

+ D1*(D1stuff1 + D1sstuff2 + D1stuff3 + D1stuff4 + D1stuff5 - D1stuff6 )

+ D2*(D2stuff)
```

How it works:

- `-v RS=`

  This tells awk to use blank lines as record separators.
- `gsub(/ *\n */, " ")`

  This tells awk to replace any newlines in the record, along with any surrounding blanks, with a single blank.
- `print $0 ORS`

  This tells awk to print the record followed by an Output Record Separator, `ORS`, which, by default, is a newline.

Answer (score 2):

On top of the very nice `awk` command introduced by [John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024), you can also use a `sed` approach for your problem.

**Input:**

```
$ cat input_file 
Dm1*(  stuff1 + stuff2 -
stuff3 + stuff4)

+ D1*(D1stuff1 + D1sstuff2 + D1stuff3 + D1stuff4 +
  D1stuff5 -
  D1stuff6 )

+ D2*(D2stuff)
```

**Command:**

```
sed -n '/^$/!{H};/^$/{x;s/\n//g;s/$/\n/;p;};${x;s/\n//g;p}' input_file
```

**Output:**

```
Dm1*(  stuff1 + stuff2 -stuff3 + stuff4)

+ D1*(D1stuff1 + D1sstuff2 + D1stuff3 + D1stuff4 +  D1stuff5 -  D1stuff6 )

+ D2*(D2stuff)
```

**Explanations:**

- `-n` deactivate `sed` auto printing
- `/^$/!{H};` When `sed` encounter a non empty line `/^$/!` append this line to the hold space via `H`
- `/^$/{x;s/\n//g;s/$/\n/;p;}` when `sed` encounter an empty line `/^$/`, exchange the hold space and the pattern space `x`, remove all `\n` in the string that has been constructed `s/\n//g`, add a `\n` at the end of the string `s/$/\n/`, print it `p`.
- `${x;s/\n//g;p}` when `sed` reaches the last line, do the exchange of hold/pattern spaces `x`, then remove all the `\n` via `s/\n//g` before printing it `p`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl paragraph mode

```
perl -00 -ne ' s/\n//g; print "$_\n\n" ' file
```

with your inputs

```
$ cat bogey.txt
Dm1*(  stuff1 + stuff2 -
stuff3 + stuff4)

+ D1*(D1stuff1 + D1sstuff2 + D1stuff3 + D1stuff4 +
  D1stuff5 -
  D1stuff6 )

+ D2*(D2stuff)
$ perl -00 -ne ' s/\n//g; print "$_\n\n" ' bogey.txt
Dm1*(  stuff1 + stuff2 -stuff3 + stuff4)

+ D1*(D1stuff1 + D1sstuff2 + D1stuff3 + D1stuff4 +  D1stuff5 -   D1stuff6 )

+ D2*(D2stuff)

$
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\n$/!s/\n//;ta' file
```

Gather up lines in the pattern space, removing newlines, until an empty line.

Comment: this works for GNU sed. However I prefer something which works on both platform GNU and BSD since I often use both.

Comment: @Boogeyman Perhaps `sed $':a;N;/\\n$/!s/\\n//;ta' file` will work or maybe `sed -e ':a' -e $'N;/\\n$/!\\n//;ta' file`